# LINQ query transfer huge amount of data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, optimization, query-optimization

I am stuck on problem with optimizing  `LINQ query` On initial load my xhr request is almost 8MB large and it took a while to take those data from server. I have list of `Auctions` where I display only few columns(which you can see in `UserAuctionListDTO`).

I uploaded image where is shown how my `DTOs` are connected for better understanding. Collections in `CurrentsToUserAccount` got only `Id` and `Name`

[image]

Goal of my query is to select all `auctions` which are assigned to `UserContact` or `Organization` or `Region` or `Department`. Auctions are valid when it has at least one `Price`.

Here is my query. It might be a bit messy but it showed me the best result with size capacity of transfered data. Each `Collection of Prices` in `UserAuctionListDTO` got around 100-1000 records, in average its about 600.

```
protected override IQueryable<UserAuctionListDTO> GetQueryable()
    {
        return AllAuctionToUser
            .Where(a => a.GarancyFromDate <= _dateTimeProvider.Now
                        && a.GarancyToDate >= _dateTimeProvider.Now
                        && !a.IsBlocked
                        && a.IsVisibleOnFe
                        && a.Prices.Any(price => price.PriceMJ > 0
                                                 && (price.Current.UserContacts.Any(x =>
                                                         x.Id == Filter.UserContactId)
                                                     || price.Current.Departments.Any(x =>
                                                         x.Id == Filter.DepartmentId)
                                                     || price.Current.Organizations.Any(x =>
                                                         x.Id == Filter.OrganizationId)
                                                     || price.Current.Regions.Any(x => x.Id == Filter.RegionId))))
            .Select(auction => new UserAuctionListDTO
            {
                Id = auction.Id,
                Code = auction.Code,
                Name = auction.Name,
                ProductCount = auction.Prices.Count,
                AttachmentsCount = auction.Attachments.Count,
                Category = new CategoryBaseDTO
                {
                    Name = auction.Category.Name
                },
                GarancyFromDate = auction.GarancyFromDate,
                GarancyToDate = auction.GarancyToDate,
                Prices = auction.Prices
                    .Select(x => new PriceToUserAuctionDTO
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Current = new CurrentsToUserAccount
                        {
                            Id = x.Current.Id,
                            UserContacts = x.Current.UserContacts.Where(u => u.IsBlocked == false)
                                .Select(z => new UserContactBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = Filter.UserContactId
                                }

                                ),
                            Departments = x.Current.Departments.Where(u => u.IsBlocked == false)
                                .Select(z => new DepartmentBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = Filter.DepartmentId
                                }),
                            Regions = x.Current.Regions.Where(u => u.IsBlocked == false)
                                .Select(z => new RegionBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = Filter.RegionId
                                }),
                            Organizations = x.Current.Organizations.Where(u => u.IsBlocked == false)
                                .Select(z => new OrganizationBaseDTO
                                {
                                    Id = Filter.OrganizationId
                                }),
                        },
                        SpecificProductSuppliers = new SpecificProductSuplierToUserAccountDTO
                        {
                            Id = x.SpecificProductSuppliers.Id,
                            CatalogName = x.SpecificProductSuppliers.CatalogName,

                            SpecificProduct = new SpecificProductToUserAccountDTO
                            {
                                Id = x.SpecificProductSuppliers.SpecificProduct.Id,
                                Name = x.SpecificProductSuppliers.SpecificProduct.Name
                            }
                        }

                    })
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Code);
    }
```

Screenshot of how much data is transfered from server
[image]

I wonder if there is anything how I can improve it.

Comment: For large amount of data I recommend using the SQL server command line tools (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine).  I like using SQLCMD.exe.  I create a SQL query and write results to a csv.  Then read the csv into the c# application.  I use the Process class to run the query so I can automate the entire process.  It is usually 10x faster than doing query inside VS.  The tools are designed to archive databases and run extremely fast.

Comment: I will give it a shot, hope it will help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: c# is lousy in giving good error messages.  So I do debugging in steps. Start by debugging SQL in SSMS.  SSME gives real good error messages.   Then create a bat file with query and run from cmd.exe.  Again the error messages in the cmd window are better than c#.

Comment: I think it would be better if you do some restructuring and create a database view for this. It would be much easier on your eyes (not to mention sanity). And if you are on sql server, you can index it to improve performance.

Comment: Is your problem the SIZE of the data returned from the webserver to the front end or the TIME it takes for the LINQ query to execute (or both)?

Comment: @Wurd Actually both, but I guess I might have to do some restructing as `Yohannes` suggested.

Comment: In long loading time scenarios I try to have one initial request that populates basic information that then kicks off some more asynchronous requests upon completion. The user then gets some info too look at instantly and the rest populates as the queries complete.

Comment: You should get a copy of LINQPad and then you can look at the actual generated SQL for the query and see what is happening. Based on the amount of data transferring (which I assume is much more than the answer), something in your LINQ is probably generated lots of SQL queries instead of one.